# Faster undo for animation

Tags: animation

I'm using 2.8 with the Spring rig and noticing undoing an action is very slow (5 seconds or so to undo an unwanted translate or rotate of a controller). Is there any way to speed this up?

Are there settings to exclude certain actions from the undo stack perhaps? For example in Maya somebody wrote a script that can exclude the selecting of objects but not the moving of them.

Thanks!